# R/Rstudio: list of "common" file extensions generated by R/RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, file-extension

I started to work at new company a few month ago. First they did not use R/RStudio, but I managed to get (almost) everything installed that I need. Unfortunately the IT department has quite a restrictive security policy and they seem to block users as soon as they generate files with unknown extension. It seems that R/RStudio generates lots of file extensions that they do not know. As I have to give them call once a week to unblock me, my workflow feels kind of bumpy.

That's why I am looking for a list of (kind of) common extensions generated by R/RStudio (also in combination with RMarkdown/RNotebooks/projects and so on) that I could give the IT department in order to reduce the times they block my user.
As an example I am looking for something like this:
.Renviron
.Rhistory
.Rproj
.R
.Rmd
.Rnd
.Rnw
.tex
.error
...

Answer (score 1):

In principle there's no such list, since you could install code that creates any possible filename.  So it really depends on what you're doing.

Here's code that will find every extension used in a particular directory (and its subdirectories).  This is a start, but once you start doing something different, you'll get a different list.

```
filenames <- basename(list.files(all.files = TRUE, recursive = TRUE))
withextension <- grep("[.]", filenames, value = TRUE)
extensions <- unique(sub(".*[.]", ".", withextension))
sort(extensions)
```

Comment: thanks for your approach even though it was not the answer I was hoping for :D ... I understand your argument, that it depends on what you are doing with R (I guess that fact contributes to the beauty of R) ... still I was looking for a list of "common (and maybe not too obivous) file extensions" (whatever that might mean) ... for example temporary/hidden files generated when working with R notebooks (like .error)